# mock db connection with testfy golang

Tags: go, mocking, testify

### Context

I have a simple [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) based Rest API implementing CRUD over a redis DB. I want to mock the redis client (*github.com/go-redis/redis/v9*) in my unit tests. Coming from OOP, I feel that I am transposing some patterns wrongly.

Here is the route I want to test (**internal/api.go**)

```golang
func GetRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()
    ...
    router.GET("/session/:sessionid", getSession)
    return router
}
```

Its controller is defined in **internal/controlers.go**

```golang
func getSession(c *gin.Context) {
    client := redis_client.GetClient()
    sessionid := c.Param("sessionid")
    val, err := client.Get(c, sessionid).Result()
    if err == redis.Nil {
        fmt.Printf("key %s not exist", sessionid)
        c.JSON(404, fmt.Sprintf("session %s not found", sessionid))
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unkown error %s", err)
        c.JSON(500, fmt.Sprintf(`{"error":"%s"}`, err))
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, val)
    }
}
```

`redis_client.GetClient` comes from one of my pkg. It's a singleton. **pkg/redis/redis.go**

```golang
var redisClient *redis.Client

func GetClient() *redis.Client {
    if redisClient == nil {
        redisClient = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
            Addr:     os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST"),
            Password: os.Getenv("REDIS_PWD"),
            DB:       0,                     
        })
    }
    return redisClient
}
```

### Testing

Spontaneously, I tried to mock either `redis.Client.Get` or `redis.StringCmd.Result`, for it is the place where the actual call to Redis occurs. In both cases, I am using `github.com/stretchr/testify/mock`

#### Moking `redis.Client.Get`

```golang
import (
    ....
    "testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type MockedRedisConn struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockedRedisConn) Get(ctx context.Context, key string) *redis.StringCmd {
    ret := m.Called(ctx, key)
    var r0 *redis.StringCmd
    if ret.Get(0) != nil {
        r0 = ret.Get(0).(*redis.StringCmd)
    }
    return r0
}

func Test_Sessions(t *testing.T) {
    r := api.GetRouter()
    redisConn := new(MockedRedisConn)
    var ctx = context.Background()
    t.Run("Should return the session", func(t *testing.T) {
        //mocks
        strCmd := redis.NewStringCmd(ctx)
        strCmd.SetVal(`{"session":""}`)
        redisConn.On("Get", mock.AnythingOfType("*gin.Context"), "00000000").Return(strCmd)

        //call
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/session/00000000", nil)

        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        r.ServeHTTP(w, req)

        responseData, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(w.Body)
        assert.Equal(t, `{"session":""}`, string(responseData))
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, w.Code)
    })
}
```

Same logic with `redis.StringCmd.Result`: I end up on a call to localhost:6379. What puzzles me is that, in [most examples I could find](https://github.com/stretchr/testify#mock-package), the mocked object is an argument of the function to be tested (I do not quite understand the point of it, by the way). In my case, it is not.

I typically miss a link to set the client in `getSession` to be my `MockedRedisConn` rather than the client given by `GetClient()` (i.e. some kind of monkey patching, if I am not mistaken). Is my singleton based setting of the client compatible with this approach? Should I rather load the client from `*gin.Context` so I could easily replace it when calling `GetRouter` in my tests?